# post_content with Contact Form 7

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7

Is it possible to add name="post_content" to more than one input field?

I am using Contact Form 7 plugin, and now only the last input field with name="post_content" is gathered in the post.

If I put the whole form in a div I only get raw data (not the filled one). Can someone help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If 2 fields have same name, web browsers ignore one of them. So you can't have the name as `name="post_content"` using contact form 7(or anything else)

You can however make the name as `name="post_content[]"` which tells the browser that the field is not single & the browser won't ignore any of them. If you use this technique, you can't use this(as far as i know) with the contact form 7 plugin. You'll need to either create the form yourself or use a plugin that supports this.